# What is my power supply rating?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I've been searching on the internet for ages and I can't seem to find out what this power supply is rated at, anyone good at reading labels?

[image: Click here for image.]

Comment: Looks like 484W Max?

Comment: Searching for the The FSP500-50AAGA model number shows that it's a 500 watts. It's also part of the model number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

500W total over the whole system. However you can't supply more than 484W *total* over 12V *and* no single 12V rail can exceed the rating stated - so 12V1 would supply 12x14w and so on.

As for why 3 rails? One for the CPU, one for the PCIe power, and one for everything else. It should work fine for most purpose. [Johnny Guru has a write up on what his means](http://www.jonnyguru.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3990), and why its a non issue. For most uses there's no advantage or disadvantage in this, but clearly this was the confusing part.

Comment: Just curious - I do realise not everyone inhales articles about hardware like I sometimes do, but which part of the label was confusing? The two different max wattages mentioned?